# Binding к свойствам, полученным через Reflection - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, рефлексия

Добрый день!

Есть класс-модель с различными свойствами (настройками), которые могут пополняться, поэтому стоит задача вытягивать эти свойства через рефлексию и генерировать нужное количество textBox для их изменения.

Eсть класс-модель с двумя свойствами, получаю их через рефлексию, Далее в Xaml делаю связывание. Связывание происходит нормально, появляются два текстбокса, однако при изменении текста, в модели ничего не меняется.. В чём может быть причина?

P.S. использую Fody, поэтому явно NotidyPropertyChanged() не вызываю в свойствах.
P.P.S. При биндинге без рефлексии всё отлично работает

Знаю, что PropertryGrid работает именно таким образом - получает поля через рефлексию и реализовывает байндинг.

Подробнее проблему с примерами кода и загруженным тестовым проектом выложил тут: [ссылка](http://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2212908.html#post12226683)

Загрузил проект на гугл диск  [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1um9O18rUK9chGci9KLCEZxmr5XdiaehQ)

```
public class Person : Notifier
{
    public string FirstName {set; get;}
    public string LastName {set; get;}
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    private void GetProperties()
    {
        Properties = new ObservableCollection<Property>();

        if (SelectedSetting != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = 
            SelectedSetting.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var pr in properties)
            {
                Properties.Add(new Property(SelectedSetting, pr));
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Property : Notifier
{
    public string PropertyName { set; get; }
    public object Value { set; get; }

    public Property(Model model, PropertyInfo pr)
    {
        PropertyName = pr.Name;
        Value = pr.GetValue(model);
    }
}

    <ListBox
            Name="Properties"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}"
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Name="LeftColumn" Width="200" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Name="RightColumn" Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=PropertyName}" />
                        <TextBox
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Text="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource PropertiesConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Думаю, что основная причина в том, что я получаю значение при помощи метода GetValue(), тем самым теряется ссылка на основной объект..  Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: У вас в Property сеттеры приватные, как вы хотите чтобы это работало? PS: Разместите весь необходимый код в вопросе.

Comment: И что же должно быть в методе Save? Я не могу получить доступ к изменившися данным, поскольку Set у свойств не срабатывает, а вытягивать каждое свойство из текстбокса - уже нарушение VM.. Можете чуть подробнее рассказать? Если приведете примеры или ссылки, было бы вообще отлично. Спасибо

Comment: Согласен по поводу приватных сеттеров, спасибо. Но это не решило проблему.. код сейчас добавлю в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не пишете измененное значение свойства обратно в объект:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
}

class PropertyVm
{
    object _source;
    PropertyInfo _propertyInfo;
    public string PropertyName { get; }

    public object Value
    {
        get => _propertyInfo.GetValue(_source);
        set => _propertyInfo.SetValue(_source,
                   Convert.ChangeType(value, _propertyInfo.PropertyType));
    }

    public PropertyVm(object source, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        _source = source;
        _propertyInfo = propertyInfo;
        PropertyName = propertyInfo.Name;
    }
}

class MainVm
{
    public Person Person { get; }
    public List<PropertyVm> Properties { get; }

    public MainVm()
    {
        Person = new Person { FirstName = "Charles", LastName = "Dow" };
        var properties = new List<PropertyVm>();
        object source = Person;
        foreach (var pi in source.GetType().GetProperties())
            properties.Add(new PropertyVm(source, pi));
        Properties = properties;
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Свойство"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Значение">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Это пример простой *прямой* реализации чтения/записи свойства. Возможно, в большинстве случаев, будет удобнее писать/читать свойство только "по команде", тогда в `PropertyVm` свойство `Value` сделайте простым автосвойством, а загрузку и выгрузку значения из/в объект перенесите в отдельные методы (или команды) Load/Save (это даже больше будет соответствовать MVVM).

Comment: Благодарю Вас, всё прекрасно работает! Понял свою ошибку