# Генерация содержимого окон wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Помогите не потеряться в логике генерации содержимого окон.

Описал контейнер окна, в которое должно помещаться динамическое содержимое в зависимости от "редактируемого" объекта.

Например, объект содержит 3 поля string и один int, необходимо его отправить на редактирование пользователю и затем измененные данные сохранить.

Не все поля редактируются, но это можно решить путем назначения данным полям атрибутов (ну и к данной проблеме не имеет отношения, как мне кажется).

**Пока что сделал:**

- Описал окно, которое будет открываться на редактирование
- Описал все независимые визуальные элементы и завел именованный grid, куда предполагал помещать TextBlock, Edit, и так далее для редактирования
- Описал примерные объекты, которые может потребоваться редактировать

**Теперь где у меня затык:**

Кто должен заниматься построением визуального редактора для объекта?

- Сам объект должен выдать UI для своего редактирования и его поместить в базовое окно?
- Окно должно принять в DataContext редактируемый объект и построить для него редактор само?

Заранее спасибо.

PS: Может очень сумбурно объяснил, просто пока не хватает еще знаний, для оперирования терминами WPF, тренируюсь на кошках.

PPS: Да, планирую еще менеджер окон, так как одновременно может редактироваться несколько объектов, который будет содержать список созданных окон и размещать их, например, на tabcontrol. Но об этом позже подумаю, хотя бы с одним объектом справиться.

Comment: Это не то что вам нужно: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid ?

Comment: Вот что-то похожее на то что вы хотите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/801385/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP про PropertyGrid думал, но как-то не очень будет смотреться. Хотелось бы несколько иначе располагать элементы на экране. Да и он кухонный комбайн, как мне кажется, для моей задачи.