# Программная генерация моделей

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Здраствуйте, есть такой вопрос. У меня в БД программно создаются таблицы, можно ли как-то генерировать модели к новым таблицам? Чтобы использовать EF.

```
namespace SettingsProject.Model
{
    public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int? client_id;
        private string project_name;
        private string description;
        private bool? enabled;

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? Client_id
        {
            get { return client_id; }
            set
            {
                client_id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Client_id");
            }
        }
        public string Project_name
        {
            get { return project_name; }
            set
            {
                project_name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Project_name");
            }
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set
            {
                description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
        public bool? Enabled
        {
            get { return enabled; }
            set
            {
                enabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Enabled");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

Вот такие модели как генерировать?! Database-First же не будет их генерировать?!

[image: Вот это как можно сделать?]

У меня таблица может создаться в процессе работы с программой. Есть встроенный редактор, который создает таблицы. Я за ранее не могу знать имя таблицы и поля в ней.

Comment: подход Database-First думаю подойдет

Comment: Это плохие модели. Не смешивайте VM и модели для EF, лишь больше мороки получите.

Comment: Ну окей пускай будет без INotifyPropertyChanged и простые свойства public int Id { get; set; }. Но как их можно сгенирировать?

Comment: Если у вас уже есть БД, и вам надо сгенерировать модели по ней, то Database-first именно это и делает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте простое консольное приложение, которое будет генерировать данные.
Мне стыдно показывать, но вот [сырой пример](https://github.com/LuridSNK/StudentsHandbook/blob/3f6282d0f3e7b0f9cf026bdf9d14592f77018f98/StudentsHandbook/StudentsHandbook.DataFiller/Filler.cs) из моего репозитория, где проект реализован посредством CodeFirst.

p.s. И я согласен с [@Андрей NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop). Модели EF не должны реализовывать никакой логики (кроме, максимум, `.ToString()`. И даже это - опционально).

Comment: Мне для MVVM необходимо это и работой с БД.

Comment: Не совсем понял сущности вашего комментария. Уточните: вам необходимо заполнить базу тестовыми данными или вы хотите генерировать данные непосредственно из приложения руками?

Comment: У меня таблица может создаться в процессе работы с программой. Есть встроенный редактор, который создает таблицы. Я за ранее не могу знать имя таблицы и поля в ней.

Comment: Если использовать стандартный подход то всё просто. Там стандартный DML DDL и верти как хочешь. А в WFP мне нужно это всё прикрепить к Binding и тд и тп.

Comment: Если у Вас есть встроенный редактор таблиц, то вы заранее знаете как названия самих таблиц, так и имя таблицы.

ЕМНИП, то в рантайме генерировать модели/классы с нуля нельзя. Так что, имхо, остатётся только генерировать данные через SqlQuery.

Поправьте, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: @LaNC1LoT, вам придется делать VM универсальную и работать через рефлексию, примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/801385/218063

Comment: Да именно так. Теперь понятно. Спасибо.